A right-angled triangle has sides of integer length. Its area (in square metres) is twice its perimeter (in metres). What are the lengths of the sides
A right-angled triangle has sides of integer length. Its area (in square metres) is twice its
perimeter (in metres). What are the lengths of the sides?
The equations I have made so far is:
Using Pythagoras' Theroem and Area Formula: $$\frac{ab}{4}=a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
Using Heron's formula:
$$s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)=4(a+b+c)^2$$
For LHS:$$(\frac{a+b+c}{2})(\frac{a+b+c-2a}{2})(\frac{a+b+c-2b}{2})
(\frac{a+b+c-2c}{2})$$
$$\frac{1}{16}((a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c))$$
$$\frac{1}{16}(((b+c)^2-a^2)(a^2-(b-c)^2))$$
Please find the original link for the question here: https://www.maths.uq.edu.au/qamt/papers/Year9-10-2022-Paper.pdf
Question 4
I believe that even though this question is simple, it is quite tricky and does need some consideration. Additionally, I needed this question's answer while I was preparing for the Year 9-10 UQ/QAMT Paper, as it still holds relevance as it still only is a 2-year old question!
My question is often compared to A right triangle with integer sides has area equal to twice its perimeter. Find sum of all possible circumradii., but I believe the question is different.

I wonder if the person who posed this problem realized how many different answers are possible.

This is kind of a general equation with many possible answers.  Are you sure no other data has been provided? If you're familiar with Heron's formula, it'll help you get the equation in a clean factorised form

This question comes from the UQ/QAMT Maths Competition. Find the link here: https://www.maths.uq.edu.au/qamt/papers/Year9-10-2022-Paper.pdf Question 4

@Gwen, yes, I tried using Heron's Formula, but I could not get the "clean factorised form" you mentioned. Perhaps you could help me with it?

It would be really good if you put what methods you have tried in your post. That will stop the downvotes. Else, it's a good question I think. Also yes I'm trying to come up with an answer

@Gwen, as per your suggestion, I added my usage of Heron's Formula.

I think the key here is that the sides are integers. I'm going to have a play with some Pythagorean triples and see where I get. My instinct is that being a middle-school paper I won't have to search far.

@drEinstein and I added my answer. Check it out :)

Does this answer your question? A right triangle with integer sides has area equal to twice its perimeter. Find sum of all possible circumradii.

I don't think you need Heron's Formula. Parameterize the triangle:
$a=2mn, b=n^2-m^2, c=n^2+m^2$
$A=\frac{ab}{2}$. $ \   \  $ $P=a+b+c.$
$A=mn\cdot (n^2-m^2)$
$P=2mn+n^2-m^2+m^2+n^2=2mn+2n^2=2n(m+n)$
$A=2P\implies mn(n^2-m^2)=4nm+4n^2$
$m(n-m)=4$
So $m$ must be a factor of $4$.
$m=1\implies n=5\implies (10, 24, 26)$
$m=2\implies n=4 \implies (16, 12,20)$
$m=4 \implies n=5 \implies (40, 9, 41)$

Heron's formula would probably be known to students sitting this paper, but I do prefer the solutions that don't use it (just personal preference).

$$\frac{ab}{4}=a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\
\implies ab=4a+4b+4\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\
\implies -4\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=4a+4b-ab \\
\implies (-4\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2=(4a+4b-ab)^2 \\
\implies 16a^2+16b^2=16a^2+16b^2+a^2 b^2 + 32ab-8a^2b-8b^2a \\
\implies 8a^2b+8b^2a=a^2b^2+32ab\\
\implies 8a+8b-ab=32\\
\implies a+b-\frac{ab}{8}=4\\
\implies b=\frac{8(a-4)}{(a-8)}$$
From here, we can get integer $b$ when $(a-8)$ is either a factor or multiple of 8. Thus $a=9,10,12,16,24,40$.
Consequently $b=40,24,16,12,10,9$.
I don't take further $a$ values because in the expression, $a-4>a-8,\frac{a-4}{a-8}>1,\frac{8(a-4)}{a-8}>8,b>8$.
Thus when I saw that at $a=40,b=9$ this meant all other greater $a$ values gave non integer $b,8<b<9$. ($b$ is decreasing as $a$ increases)
Magically enough, all these pairs are Pythagorean triplets.
$$9^2+40^2=41^2,12^2+16^2=20^2,24^2+10^2=26^2$$

First we apply a lemma

Lemma. Let $p,r,A$ be the perimeter, inscribed radius and the area of the triangle respectively. Then we have $pr=2A$.

The proof is easy, just because radius of inscribed circle is perpendicular to triangle side, so we can divide it into three slices, and $\cdots$
Now with this fact, we have $pr=2A=4p$, so we get $r=4$.
From now on, we let the triangle be $\Delta ABC$ with $\angle A$ is right angle. set $I_C,I_B$ be the projection of the incenter on the line $AB$ and $AC$ respectively. Note $AI_B=AI_C=r=4$. Let $I_BC=t,I_CB=s$. By tangent property we have $BC=s+t$. By pythagorus theorem, we have $$(4+s)^2+(4+t)^2=(s+t)^2$$
Rearranging we get (Here we know $c\ne4$, can you do it yourself?)$$s=\dfrac{4t+16}{t-4}=4+\dfrac{32}{t-4}$$
Thus, we have $t-4$ is a factor of $32$, i.e. $$t-4=1,2,4,8,16,32\iff (s,t)=(36,5),(20,6),(12,8),(8,12),(6,20),(5,36)$$
Now I give you a task, is to verify how much of them is actually a solution.

OP has already given meaning to $b$ and $c$, perhaps you should use some other letters if your $b$ and $c$ aren't the same as those of OP.

yah that's a good idea, i will adjust it.

Check your ordered pairs for $s$ and $t$. They should be symmetrical, that is a given $(s,t)$ should be accompanied by $(t,s)$. A correct rendering gives no extraneous solutions but counts the good ones twice due to this symmetry.

arh yes I'm too lazy to check it, thanks for pointing out.

Let $a$ and $b$ be the legs. Then the area $ab/2$ doubles the perimeter $a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. So
$ab=4(a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}).$
Multiply by the conjugate $a+b-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and apply the difference of squares factorization to simplify the right side:
$ab(a+b-\sqrt{a^2+b^2})=8ab$
$a+b-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=8$
$a+b-8=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$
$a^2+2ab-16a+b^2-16b+64=a^2+b^2$
$2ab-16a-16b+64=2(ab-8a-8b+32)=0$
So
$(a-8)(b-8)=ab-8a-8b+64=32,$
and we identify three distinct triangles:
$a-8=1,b-8=32\implies a=9,b=40,c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a+b-8=41$
$a-8=2,b-8=16\implies a=10,b=24,c=26$
$a-8=4,b-8=8\implies a=12,b=16,c=20.$
